# Receiving Error Message When Attempting to Import Googleads with Python

Tags: python, pip, google-ads-api

Attempting to use the googleads adwords api

```
from googleads import adwords
```

and get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleads'
```

I had previous done the

```
python -m pip install google-ads
```

and am running on a macbook pro

How do I resolve this?

*Edit*

I didn't set up an active virtual environment first, could that be the issue? And as an aside, why is that necessary?

Comment: API example: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/samples/get-campaigns#python

Comment: so is it missing the `google.ads.googleads.client`?

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the Python Library changed the name of the module.

https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/issues/475

> the module path changed from google_ads to googleads, removing the
> underscore (_). For all usage of v10 and onward, you should use import
> google.ads.googleads